# Какие есть способы перемещения зажатием мыши svg изображения на js?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Голову ломаю на тем как увеличенное svg изображение можно двигать в браузере. Может какая функция есть или способ?
Вот что я наделал:

```js
var leftArrow        = 37; // The numeric code for the left arrow key.
    var upArrow          = 38;
    var rightArrow       = 39;
    var downArrow        = 40;
    var panRate          = 10; // Number of pixels to pan per key press.    
    var zoomRate         = 1.1; // Must be greater than 1. Increase this value for faster zooming (i.e., less granularity).
    var x;
    var y;
    /* Globals: */
    var theSvgElement;
    
    function processKeyPress(evt)
    {
      var viewBox = theSvgElement.getAttribute('viewBox'); // Grab the object representing the SVG element's viewBox attribute.
      var viewBoxValues = viewBox.split(' ');    // Create an array and insert each individual view box attribute value (assume they're seperated by a single whitespace character).

      viewBoxValues[0] = parseFloat(viewBoxValues[0]);  // Convert string "numeric" values to actual numeric values.
      viewBoxValues[1] = parseFloat(viewBoxValues[1]);
      
      switch (evt.keyCode)
      {
        case leftArrow:
          viewBoxValues[0] += panRate; // Increase the x-coordinate value of the viewBox attribute to pan right.
          break;
        case rightArrow:
          viewBoxValues[0] -= panRate; // Decrease the x-coordinate value of the viewBox attribute to pan left.
          break;
        case upArrow:
          viewBoxValues[1] += panRate; // Increase the y-coordinate value of the viewBox attribute to pan down.
          break;
        case downArrow:
          viewBoxValues[1] -= panRate; // Decrease the y-coordinate value of the viewBox attribute to pan up.      
          break;                         
      } // switch
      
      theSvgElement.setAttribute('viewBox', viewBoxValues.join(' ')); // Convert the viewBoxValues array into a string with a white space character between the given values.
    }
    function drag(evt) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('svg-id', evt.target.id);
}
    function zoom(zoomType)
    {
      var viewBox = theSvgElement.getAttribute('viewBox'); // Grab the object representing the SVG element's viewBox attribute.
      var viewBoxValues = viewBox.split(' ');    // Create an array and insert each individual view box attribute value (assume they're seperated by a single whitespace character).

      viewBoxValues[2] = parseFloat(viewBoxValues[2]);  // Convert string "numeric" values to actual numeric values.
      viewBoxValues[3] = parseFloat(viewBoxValues[3]);
      
      if (zoomType == 'zoomIn')
      {
        viewBoxValues[2] /= zoomRate; // Decrease the width and height attributes of the viewBox attribute to zoom in.
        viewBoxValues[3] /= zoomRate; 
      }
      else if (zoomType == 'zoomOut')
      {
        viewBoxValues[2] *= zoomRate; // Increase the width and height attributes of the viewBox attribute to zoom out.
        viewBoxValues[3] *= zoomRate; 
      }
      else
        alert("function zoom(zoomType) given invalid zoomType parameter.");
      
      theSvgElement.setAttribute('viewBox', viewBoxValues.join(' ')); // Convert the viewBoxValues array into a string with a white space character between the given values.
      
      var currentZoomFactor = svgViewBoxWidth / viewBoxValues[2];          // Calculates the current zoom factor, could have just as easily used svgViewBoxHeight.      
      var newText = document.createTextNode("Current zoom factor = " + currentZoomFactor.toFixed(3)); // Create a generic new text node object.
      var parentNode = document.getElementById('currentZoomFactorText');          // Get the parent node of the text node we want to replace.
      
      parentNode.replaceChild(newText, parentNode.firstChild);  // Replace the first child text node with the new text object.
    }
        
    function zoomViaMouseWheel(mouseWheelEvent)
    {      
      if (mouseWheelEvent.wheelDelta > 0)
        zoom('zoomIn');
      else
        zoom('zoomOut');
        
      /* When the mouse is over the webpage, don't let the mouse wheel scroll the entire webpage: */
      mouseWheelEvent.cancelBubble = false; 
      return false;       
    } 
  
    function initialize()
    {        
      /* Add event listeners: */
      window.addEventListener('keydown', processKeyPress, true);  // OK to let the keydown event bubble.
      window.addEventListener('mousewheel', zoomViaMouseWheel, false); // Don't let the mousewheel event bubble up to stop native browser window scrolling.
           
      /* Set a global variable and detect if the browser supports SVG: */
      theSvgElement = document.getElementById('svg-id');   // Best to only access the SVG element after the page has fully loaded.
     
   document.addEventListener("drag", function( event ) {

  }, false);
  
      if(theSvgElement.namespaceURI != "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg") // Alert the user if their browser does not support SVG.
        alert("Inline SVG in HTML5 is not supported. This document requires a browser that supports HTML5 inline SVG.");
            
      /* For the svg element, specifically set the viewBox attribute's width and height values in that one of them will be used to calculate the current scaling factor. */
      theSvgElement.setAttribute('viewBox', "0 0 " + svgViewBoxWidth + " " + svgViewBoxHeight); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var leftArrow  = 37
  , upArrow    = 38
  , rightArrow = 39
  , downArrow  = 40
  , panRate    = 10
  , zoomRate   = 1.1
  , dragScale = 1
  , x, y, theSvgElement;
    
function processKeyPress(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var viewBoxValues = theSvgElement.getAttribute('viewBox').split(' ');
  viewBoxValues[0] = parseFloat(viewBoxValues[0]);
  viewBoxValues[1] = parseFloat(viewBoxValues[1]);
  var offset = panRate / dragScale;
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case leftArrow:
      viewBoxValues[0] += offset;
      break;
      
    case rightArrow:
      viewBoxValues[0] -= offset;
      break;
      
    case upArrow:
      viewBoxValues[1] += offset;
      break;
      
    case downArrow:
      viewBoxValues[1] -= offset;
      break;         
  }
  theSvgElement.setAttribute('viewBox', viewBoxValues.join(' '));
}
    
function zoom(zoomType) { 
  var viewBoxValues = theSvgElement.getAttribute('viewBox').split(' ');
  viewBoxValues[2] = parseFloat(viewBoxValues[2]);
  viewBoxValues[3] = parseFloat(viewBoxValues[3]);
  if (zoomType === 'zoomIn') {
    viewBoxValues[2] /= zoomRate;
    viewBoxValues[3] /= zoomRate; 
  }
  else if (zoomType === 'zoomOut') {
    viewBoxValues[2] *= zoomRate;
    viewBoxValues[3] *= zoomRate; 
  }
  theSvgElement.setAttribute('viewBox', viewBoxValues.join(' '));
  dragScale = svgViewBoxWidth / parseFloat(viewBoxValues[2]);
}
        
function zoomViaMouseWheel(e) {
  e.preventDefault();      
  e.wheelDelta > 0 ? zoom('zoomIn') : zoom('zoomOut');
}
    
function mouseDown(e) {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
  var viewBoxValues = theSvgElement.getAttribute('viewBox').split(' ');
  x = e.pageX + parseFloat(viewBoxValues[0]) * dragScale;
  y = e.pageY + parseFloat(viewBoxValues[1]) * dragScale;
  theSvgElement.querySelector('circle').classList.add('dragging');
}
    
function mouseMove(e) {
  var viewBoxValues = theSvgElement.getAttribute('viewBox').split(' ');
  viewBoxValues[0] = (x - e.pageX) / dragScale;
  viewBoxValues[1] = (y - e.pageY) / dragScale;
  theSvgElement.setAttribute('viewBox', viewBoxValues.join(' '));
}
    
function mouseUp(e) {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
  theSvgElement.querySelector('circle').classList.remove('dragging');
};
  
function initialize() {        
  window.addEventListener('keydown', processKeyPress, true);
  window.addEventListener('mousewheel', zoomViaMouseWheel, false);
  theSvgElement = document.getElementById('svg-id');
  document.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);
  theSvgElement.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 ' + svgViewBoxWidth + ' ' + svgViewBoxHeight); 
}

var svgViewBoxWidth = window.innerWidth
  , svgViewBoxHeight = window.innerHeight;
initialize();
```

```html
<svg id="svg-id">
  <defs>
    <style>
      circle {
        cursor: grab;
        cursor: -moz-grab;
        cursor: -webkit-grab;
      }
      circle.dragging {
        cursor: grabbing;
        cursor: -moz-grabbing;
        cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <circle class="circle" cx="311" cy="107" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, @Alex, ты лучший!!!

Comment: класс, спасибо огромное !!!!!!